# How can I reset variables to their default values?

Tags: java, android

I am an IT student in 2nd year. I am making a wholesale app.

How it works:

> First the user browses for an item in the store. The data of a selected item is used to create an object. The object is added to an ArrayList that acts as the user's cart. This ArrayList and its contemporary data can be seen in a Cart activity and a Receipt/Checkout activity.
>
> Pressing the OK button in the Receipt activity duplicates the arraylist, stores the duplicate in the Order History, finally it clears the original arraylist and goes back to the main menu.

***Shopping Activity***

```
package com.example.wearhouse;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.material.chip.Chip;
import com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup;

public class encodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    // set defaults
    private String empty_STR = "";
    private int empty_INT = 0;
    private final static String DEFAULT_STR = null;
    private final static int DEFAULT_INT = 0;

    /*  For individual orders: These data will be passed to the listitem class  */
    private volatile int item_quantity;
    private volatile String item_type;
    private volatile String item_color;
    /*                                                    */


    // represents items in bill
    protected static ArrayList<listitem> checkoutSTRUCT = new ArrayList<>();

    /* START */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_encode);

        TextView shirtCOUNTER, shortsCOUNTER;
        EditText notesENTRY, paymentENTRY, quantityCOUNTER;
        ImageButton shirtBTN, shortsBTN;
        Button decBTN, incBTN, billBTN;
        ChipGroup colorCG;
        RadioGroup sex, sizing;
        Spinner paymodeSPIN, discountSPIN;

        shirtCOUNTER = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shirtCOUNTER);
        shortsCOUNTER = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shortsCOUNTER);
        quantityCOUNTER = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityENTRY);

        paymentENTRY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.received_paymentENTRY);

        try {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide Action bar
            Integer.parseInt(quantityCOUNTER.getText().toString());

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            quantityCOUNTER.setText("1"); // set default quantity multiplier
            paymentENTRY.setText( String.valueOf(DEFAULT_INT) );

        }

        // widgets
        notesENTRY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notesENTRY);

        decBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decBTN);
        incBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incBTN);
        billBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.billBTN);

        shirtBTN = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.shirtBTN);
        shortsBTN = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.shortsBTN);

        sex = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sexRG);
        sizing = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sizeRG);

        colorCG = (ChipGroup) findViewById(R.id.colorCG);

        paymodeSPIN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.paymode);
        discountSPIN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.discountSPIN);

        // mode of payment
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterPM = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.payMode, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterPM.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        paymodeSPIN.setAdapter(adapterPM);

        // discount
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterDS = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.discountMode, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterDS.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        discountSPIN.setAdapter(adapterDS);

        // listeners
        {
            sex.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedR) {
                    checkedR = sex.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton temp = findViewById(checkedR);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected " + temp.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            sizing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedR) {
                    checkedR = sizing.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton temp = findViewById(checkedR);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Size " + temp.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            shirtBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Chip tempCHIP;
                    final int tempCOLOR;
                    final float item_cost;

                    // get selected color
                    tempCOLOR = colorCG.getCheckedChipId();
                    tempCHIP = findViewById(tempCOLOR);
                    item_color = (String) tempCHIP.getText();

                    // get selected quantity
                    item_quantity = Integer.parseInt( quantityCOUNTER.getText().toString() );
                    System.out.println("item_quantity: " + item_quantity);

                    // get cost based on quantity
                    item_cost = item_quantity * 150;

                    item_type = "SHIRT";
                    System.out.println("item_type: " + item_type);

                    // add to cart
                    checkoutSTRUCT.add(new listitem(item_quantity, item_color, item_type, item_cost));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getCount(checkoutSTRUCT, item_type) + " " + item_type, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // update counter
                    shirtCOUNTER.setText( String.valueOf( getQuantity_Sum(checkoutSTRUCT, item_type) ) );

                    // reset values
                    // FIXME this does not work; find another way to clear @item_quantity, @item_color, and @item_type
                    item_quantity = empty_INT;
                    item_color = empty_STR;
                    item_type = empty_STR;
                }
            });

            shortsBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Chip tempCHIP;
                    final int tempCOLOR;
                    final float item_cost;


                    System.out.println("item_color" + item_color);

                    // get selected color
                    tempCOLOR = colorCG.getCheckedChipId();
                    tempCHIP = findViewById(tempCOLOR);
                    item_color = (String) tempCHIP.getText();

                    // get selected quantity
                    System.out.println("item_quantity: " + item_quantity);
                    item_quantity = Integer.parseInt( quantityCOUNTER.getText().toString() );

                    // get cost based on quantity
                    item_cost = item_quantity * 150;

                    System.out.println("item_type: " + item_type);
                    item_type = "SHORTS";

                    // add to cart
                    checkoutSTRUCT.add(new listitem(item_quantity, item_color, item_type, item_cost));
                    System.out.println("expected: ");
                    System.out.println("item_color" + item_color);
                    System.out.println("item_quantity: " + item_quantity);
                    System.out.println("item_type: " + item_type);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getCount(checkoutSTRUCT, item_type) + " " + item_type, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    shortsCOUNTER.setText(String.valueOf( getQuantity_Sum(checkoutSTRUCT, item_type) ));

                    // reset values
                    item_quantity = empty_INT;
                    item_color = empty_STR;
                    item_type = empty_STR;
                }
            });

            decBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {

                        String x = String.valueOf(quantityCOUNTER.getText());


                        int value = Integer.parseInt(x);
                        if (value > 1)
                            value--;

                        String valueSTR = String.valueOf(value);
                        quantityCOUNTER.setText(valueSTR);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        quantityCOUNTER.setText("1");
                        decBTN.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            incBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        String x = String.valueOf(quantityCOUNTER.getText());

                        int value = Integer.parseInt(x);
                        value++;

                        String valueSTR = String.valueOf(value);
                        quantityCOUNTER.setText(valueSTR);

                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        quantityCOUNTER.setText("1");
                        decBTN.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            billBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String payment_mode = String.valueOf(paymodeSPIN.getSelectedItem());

                    // open gcash app if GCash is selected
                    if (payment_mode.equals("GCash")) {
                        makeGCASH();
                    }

                    if (payment_mode.equals("In-person")) {
                        makeBill();
                    }
                }
            });

            paymodeSPIN.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            discountSPIN.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                // save and pass spinner ITEM SELECTED data
                private final SharedPreferences dataLOCAL = getSharedPreferences("MySavedData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                private final SharedPreferences.Editor dataEDIT = dataLOCAL.edit();

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String discountSELECTED = String.valueOf(discountSPIN.getSelectedItem());
                    float discountPERCENT;
                    double toPERCENT = 0.01f;


                    switch (discountSELECTED) {
                        case "SENIOR CITIZEN/PWD":
                        case "STUDENT":
                            Toast.makeText(encodeActivity.this, "20% OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            discountPERCENT = (float) (20 * toPERCENT);

                            dataEDIT.putFloat("data_discount", discountPERCENT);
                            dataEDIT.commit();

                            break;

                        case "OFW/BALIKBAYAN":
                            Toast.makeText(encodeActivity.this, "10% OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            discountPERCENT = (float) (10 * toPERCENT);

                            dataEDIT.putFloat("data_discount", discountPERCENT);
                            dataEDIT.commit();

                            break;

                        case "NONE":
                            discountPERCENT = (0);
                            dataEDIT.putFloat("data_discount", discountPERCENT);
                            dataEDIT.commit();

                            break;

                        default:
                            Toast.makeText(encodeActivity.this, "!! discount NOT FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }

    }

    /* Generic Listeners */
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text + "DISCOUNT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v) {
        // generic radiobutton listener
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    /* Custom Methods */

    // open another app to make cashless payment
    private void makeGCASH() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paying GCash", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // com.globe.gcash.android
        Intent my_intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.globe.gcash.android");
        startActivity(my_intent);
    }

    // go to the bill
    private void makeBill() {
        float amt_received;
        EditText paymentENTRY;

        paymentENTRY = findViewById(R.id.received_paymentENTRY);
        amt_received = Float.parseFloat(paymentENTRY.getText().toString());

        Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, billActivity.class);
        my_intent.putExtra("received_amt", amt_received);
        startActivity(my_intent);
    }

    // get instances of object types
    private int getCount(ArrayList<listitem> cart, String type){

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
            if ( cart.get(i).GETtype_listitem().equals( type ) )
            { count++; }
        }

        return count;
    }

    private int getQuantity_Sum(ArrayList<listitem> cart, String type){

        int tempSum= 0;
        for (int i = 0;

             i < cart.size()
             &&
             cart.get(i).GETtype_listitem().equals( type );

             i++
        )
        { tempSum = tempSum + cart.get(i).GETqty_listitem(); }

        return tempSum;
    }
    
}
```

---

[image]

In my first attempt, the onclick event will create duplicate orders if I change the color.

[image: This was my first attempt at implementing functionality]

The second attempt failed because it adds an item with 0 quantity attribute, and I need to click on the item button more than once to actually change its respective counter

This is what happens when I click once

[image: This is what happens when I click once]

This is what happen when I click 3 times.

[image: This is what happen when I click 3 times.]

Result:

[image: This is the end result]

How can I reset the `item_quantity`, `item_color`, and `item_type` variables so that a new object does not read the attributes of a previous object?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have them scoped to the class instead of scoped to the listener.
I have cleaned up your code and added them as local variables to the listener.

```
        shirtBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Chip chip = findViewById(colorCG.getCheckedChipId());
                String color = chip.getText().toString();
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt( quantityCOUNTER.getText().toString());
                float cost = quantity * 150;
                String type = "SHIRT";

                checkoutSTRUCT.add(new listitem(quantity, color, type, cost));
                shirtCOUNTER.setText( String.valueOf( getQuantity_Sum(checkoutSTRUCT, type)));
            }
        });
```

This creates new local variables for every click instead of using the same one every time.

Also please refer to the java naming conventions, standardized code is very important. For example: "quantityCOUNTER", "item_cost" "listitem" do not follow the convention.

Comment: I've applied your suggestion, but Toast message says that the new object reads some other value.

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d724X1i3LhVN5CPKWBBNew3L1K0oA_Md/view?usp=share_link)